# fetch rows based on another activity in mysql

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery, gaps-and-islands

I have one mysql  table of user_locations. I have records like below

```
id    user_id     latitude                 longitude
 1      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
 2      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
 3      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
 4      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
 5      1         28.627457222222223       77.11092111111111
 6      1         28.627457222222223       77.11092111111111
 7      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
 8      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
```

Now see id 1,2,3,4,7,8 having same latitude and longitude and id 5,6 having different latitude longitude

if i group by i get only two results. But My expected output is like below:-

```
 id    user_id     latitude                 longitude
 4      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
 6      1         28.627457222222223       77.11092111111111
 8      1         28.62584611111111        77.10560666666667
```

I have tried below query but that gives me two results

```
SELECT * FROM `user_locations` WHERE `user_id` = 1 Group by latitude, longitude
```

What i want to find if same latitude and longitude constantly occur it must return one latest row and after that if changes in latitude and longitude then that latest row will come and if in between again same latitude and longitude came from pevious sets that should also return. Hope you understand my problem. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Incidentally, on Earth, the eighth decimal place represents an accuracy of approximately 1mm.

Comment: locations came i database in every 10 seconds

Comment: did you got my problem? what i am trying to acheive?.. in this group by doesn't work

Comment: @Strawberry have you check my expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. Islands represents adjacent rows having the same user, latitude and longitude, and you want the last record of each island.

Here the simplest approach is probably to use `lag()` to identify the changes in latitude/longitude:

```
select *
from (
    select ul.*,
        lag(latitude) over(partition by user_id order by id) lag_latitude,
        lag(longitude) over(partition by user_id order by id) lag_longitude
    from user_locations ul
) ul
where latitude <> lag_latitude or longitude <> lag_longitude
```

---

This requires MariaDB 12.2.2 or higher. In earlier versions, you can emulate window functions with correlated subqueries. This will probably be inefficient over a large number of rows:

```
select *
from user_locations ul
where latitude  <> (select ul1.latitude  from user_locations ul1 where ul1.user_id = ul.user_id and ul1.id < ul.id order by ul1.id desc limit 1)
   or longitude <> (select ul1.longitude from user_locations ul1 where ul1.user_id = ul.user_id and ul1.id < ul.id order by ul1.id desc limit 1)
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by user_id order by id) lag_latitude,
        lag(longitude, 1, long' at line 4

Comment: @kunal: you need MariaDB 10.2.2 or higher. Which version are you running? `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: 10.1.47 @GMB i dont have access to update the version can we have another solution for this version 10.1.47?

Comment: @kunal: I fixed the first query for MariaDB (you tagged your question MySQL initially, and the syntax differs slightly). I also added another solution for earlier versions.

Comment: @kunal: `user_id = 1 and (latitude <> ... or longitude <> ...)`